# HTTP response codes coming wrongly where it is actually 200

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to extract the HTTP links from an XML. Then trying to get the http response code for the same. But interestingly, i am getting either 500 or 400. If i click on the url, i will get the image properly in the browser.

My Code is:

```
def extract_src_link(path):
with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if "src" in line:
            src_link = re.search('src=(.+?)ptype="2"', line)
            url = src_link.group(1)
            url = url[1:-1]
            #print ("url:", url)
            resp = requests.head(url)
            print(resp.status_code)
```

Not sure whats happening here. This is how my output looks like

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 
/Users/rradhakrishnan/Projects/eVision/Scripts/xml_validator_ver3.py
Processing: 
/Users/rradhakrishnan/rradhakrishnan1/mobily/E30000001554522119_2020_01_27T17_35_40Z.xml
500
404
Processing: 
/Users/rradhakrishnan/rradhakrishnan1/mobily/E30000001557496079_2020_01_27T17_35_40Z.xml
500
404
```

This is how my output looks like:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to crack it down. Adding the User Agent did resolve the issue.

```
def extract_src_link(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            if "src" in line:
                src_link = re.search('src=(.+?)ptype="2"', line)
                url = src_link.group(1)
                url = url[1:-1]
                print ("url:", url)
                # resp = requests.head(url)
                # print(resp.status_code)
                headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36'}

                r = requests.get('http://www.booking.com/reviewlist.html?cc1=tr;pagename=sapphire', headers=headers)
                print r.status_code
```